# can cassandra use multiple native secondary indexes when querying on mutiple indexed columns?

Tags: cassandra

can cassandra use multiple native secondary indexes when querying on mutiple indexed columns?

using the canonical example from http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/whats-new-cassandra-07-secondary-indexes

assuming a users column family with indexes both on birth date and state:

```
create column family users with comparator=UTF8Type
  and column_metadata=[{column_name: full_name, validation_class: UTF8Type},
  {column_name: birth_date, validation_class: LongType, index_type: KEYS},
  {column_name: state, validation_class: UTF8Type, index_type: KEYS}];
```

when I query:

```
get users where state = 'UT' and birth_date = 1970;
```

does cassandra uses both indexes to fetch the rows?

based on [Compound Indexes in Apache Cassandra](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4558269/compound-indexes-in-apache-cassandra) it seems the answer is no

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The link you give is correct; Cassandra will pick the most-selective index and use a nested loop to evaluate other predicates.

Comment: Does it do that in the server side or the client side (transmitting whole data over the wire and evaluating the rest of the query locally)?